# How do I parse a primitive of a Json File?

Tags: c#, json

I have the following JSON file from a Get Request:

```
{
"vcalendar": [
    {
        "version": "2.0",
        "prodid": " CalendarID",
        "vevent": [
            {
                "uid": " EventID",
                "dtstamp": "20180725T000000",
                "status": "CONFIRMED",
                "dtstart": [
                    "20180213",
                    {
                        "value": "DATE"
                    }
                ],
                "dtend": [
                    "20180214",
                    {
                        "value": "DATE"
                    }
                ],
                "summary": " Event subject",
                "description": "Event description"
            }
     ]
    }
],
"success": true
}
```

And I want to get the dtstart and dtend primitive number in this case it would be "20180213" and "20180214", but I can't deserialize the JSON File how I usually do it in order to get the information I want.

To get the other values I use:

```
public class iCalendarFile
{

    public List<iCalendar> vcalendar { get; set; }
}

public class iCalendar
{
    public List<iCalendarEvent> vevent { get; set; }
}

public class iCalendarEvent
{
    public string summary { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public List<string> dtstart { get; set; }
    public List<string> dtend { get; set; }
}
```

And deserialize it like that:

```
public static async void makeGetRequest(TraceWriter log) {
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);


        var result = reader.ReadToEnd();
        var jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<iCalendarFile>(result);

        foreach (iCalendar icalobject in jsonObject.vcalendar ) {
            foreach (iCalendarEvent Object in icalobject.vevent)
             {


               foreach(String tmp in Object.dtstart){
                    log.Info(tmp);
                }

             }
          }

        reader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        response.Close();
}
```

My Error is:

Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path 'vcalendar[0].vevent[0].dtstart[0]', line 1, position 238.
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadStringValue(ReadType readType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadAsString()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadForType(JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter)

If you have any Idea how to access the value in dtstart I would be grateful. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you try to change variable from List<string> to List<object>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the first change JSON Class with that (https://jsonutils.com/)

```
#region JsonClass
    public class Vevent
    {
        public string uid { get; set; }
        public string dtstamp { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
        public IList<object> dtstart { get; set; }
        public IList<object> dtend { get; set; }
        public string summary { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
    }

    public class Vcalendar
    {
        public string version { get; set; }
        public string prodid { get; set; }
        public IList<Vevent> vevent { get; set; }
    }

    public class iCalendarFile
    {
        public IList<Vcalendar> vcalendar { get; set; }
        public bool success { get; set; }
    }
#endregion
```

After That u can:

```
var jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<iCalendarFile>(sb);
for (int i = 0; i < jsonObject.vcalendar[0].vevent[0].dtstart.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(jsonObject.vcalendar[0].vevent[0].dtstart[i].ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

dtstart and dtend variables can not be deserialized as string.

Please, Try to change variable to `List<string>` from  `List<object>`

Answer (score 0):

If you need only dtstart/dtend values, you can try something like this:

```
dynamic jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);
string dtstart = jsonObject.vcalendar[0].vevent[0].dtstart[0];
string dtend = jsonObject.vcalendar[0].vevent[0].dtstart[0];
```